# Not able to scroll LinearLayout which contain a line graph and a spinner inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem of scrolling a linearlayout which have a Line graph in it.
The line graph is added dynamically to the linear layout.Below is the layout of my activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#004F96"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back2"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>



 <ScrollView  android:id="@+id/chartttt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Below is some of my java code

```
Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(15*scale);
    canvas.drawLine(50*scale,20*scale,50*scale, 250*scale, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(50*scale,250*scale,300*scale, 250*scale, paint);

     Path path = new Path();
        //RectF rect = new RectF(offset_left*0.33f, y_translate_factor+(lineChartAttributes.Y_unit_name.length()*5), offset_left*0.33f, y_translate_factor-(lineChartAttributes.Y_unit_name.length()*5));
        RectF rect = new RectF(15*scale, 150*scale,40*scale, 250*scale);
        path.addRect(rect , Direction.CCW);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawTextOnPath(ytext, path, 10*scale, 0, paint);
```

The Line chart is a class that extends View.
When i add another views below the graph the layout doesn't scroll.

Answer (score -1):

You must use `wrap_content` on your LinearLayout that is inside your ScrollView.